# List number of items by date

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of item:

```
 class Item { 
      DateTime Start {get;set;}
      DateTime End {get;set;}
  }
```

With start and end beeing days, ex: `09/08/2013`

I need to make a list of : `(DateTime x - how many items with Start >x and End < x)`

I could do this:

```
  list(DateTime x, int HowMany) results
  dayZero = Earliest start day
  dayFinal = Latest end day
  for (currentDay : dayZero to dayFinal)
       put (currentDay,Get How Many Items with start>currentDay, end<currentDay)
```

But the problem is that items are dispersed in time, i will be calculating number of items for a lot of days without changes on the number of total items.
I think the best solution is iterating only over the initial and final days of items, but what is the best way to do it more performant?

I am using linq, so i have:

```
protected readonly OL4RENTDb _context;
IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<Item>();
query.Where <- ????
```

Comment: How are you iterating over "the initial and final days of items"? What do you want more performant.. The pseudo code is kind of weird.. what does put do, and is "Get How Many Items with start>currentday" some sort of comparison of a count and a datetime?

Comment: And your title suggests that you want to order the items, or am I misinterpreting? I can't figure out what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: more performant, the faster query to acomplish by the db manager.

Comment: the psuedo code is simple: put = add to list and get how many items with start> currentday means just doing that, it simple to do (iterate over the collection) so i didnt put it in the pseudocode

Comment: Do `>` and `<` mean 'before' and 'after' respectively?

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + end.Subtract(start).Days)
.Select(offset=>new {
     day=start.AddDays(offset),
     count=Items.Count(i=>i.Start<start.AddDays(offset) && 
     i.End>start.AddDays(offset)});
```

I think should work, given that start=starting date, end=ending date, Items is a collection of Item.

Comment: Yes, but supouse:   Item1: (12/12/1990-12/12/2010) Item2(12/12/2009-12/12/2020) In that case, you will iterate over each day of years 1990-2010, calculating for each one the number of items at that day, and without changes. I think it can be more efficient if you do not iterate over each day

Comment: Well it depends on your data of course.  Are you expecting a small number of items with large ranges or a large number of items with small ranges?

Comment: A small number of items with large ranges, thats the problem :)